# changing a project template in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, project-template

How can I change Intellij Idea's Node.js express *project template* as seen here:
[image: screenshot]

To have an option "none" under Template?

Comment: I don't know anything regarding node since I have never used it, but have you considered creating a project and editing it for your needs and then saving it as a template? This should allow you to create your project the way you want eveytime. Please see this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/saving-projects-as-templates.html?origin=old_help) for more info on how to create the project template.

Comment: yes I have. In fact that was the previous question I asked and I've since worked with such a project :) however, it would be nice to expand upon the node.js + express project template, since it structurally belongs there.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really be done, but:

- make a backup of the whole thing
- remove .idea and .iml files
- create a new project of the desired type/template
- make the location of the project the same as the original project.

That will probably trash a lot of things, but you will have your files and a project of the right type/template